# as a user, can I surpress sms alerts in the notification bar on android 2.1 (alert - but not show the first line of text)?

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

as an end user, can I surpress sms alerts in the notification bar on android 2.1 (alert - but not show the first line of text)?
Is there a phone setting? Or an app out there that allows this choice?

Comment: As user, you better ask here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be moved to https://android.stackexchange.com/.  Anyway, if you download Handcent SMS, there is an option to receive texts in "Private Mode", where it shows the icon, but not who it's from and the content of the message.  Also, you'd need to turn off notifications in the standard Messaging app.